# 2 Div's closing in and remove 1 div in between

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for (I think?) a jQuery script where I can slide remove 1 div and let 1 div slide up as the other div disappears.

I made a little drawing to show what i mean.
[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOrVD.png)

So I want the red part to slide up and be removed, and the yellow bar under it has to slide with it but not disappear and hug the blue header bar.
And I want this to happen when a button is clicked.

Someone knows how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery to animate the height shrinking and in the complete handler, remove it:

```
$("button").click(function() {
 $("#reddiv").animate({height: 0}, {complete: function() {
    $(this).remove();
 }});
});
```

With this CSS:

```
#reddiv {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#yellowdiv {
  background-color: #ffff00;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mcgraphix/mmm1pvov/

Comment: Thanks that was what i was looking for! But do u know how  to show the reddiv again when the button is pressed again?

Comment: I saw u editted your jsfiddle, I used it and it works now, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Great. I tried to post a comment but SO was down for maintenance at the time.